# Check to see if the file "/etc/shadow" exists

Tags: linux

Write a shell script to check to see if the file "/etc/shadow" exists. If it does exist, display
"Shadow passwords are enabled." Next, check to see if you can write to the file. If you can,
display "You have permissions to edit /etc/shadow." If you cannot, display "You do NOT have
permissions to edit /etc/shadow."

I am a naive in scripting and trying to understand the same. I am able to cover the first part of the question. However I am not able to understand how should I make a move with the next part of the question.

In the below code if I try to add a command argument to check which is vi /etc/shadow, I am not getting how do write the command where it does vi /etc/shadow and based on the command as permission denied it should echo: there is no permission on this.

Please help.

First Part is as under:

```
#! /bin/bash
file1=$(cd /etc | grep shadow)

if(f1=$file1)
then
    echo "Shadow passwords are enabled."
fi
```

Comment: I see a few problems with this script. First, line 2 is not setting `file1` to anything: you are taking the output of the `cd` command, and searching it for the string `shadow`. The problem is that `cd` will not produce any output. You might want to replace `cd` with `ls`, which is still not the best approach, but it's better...

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple one and here is the answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -f /etc/shadow ]] && echo "Shadow passwords are enabled."
[[ -w /etc/shadow ]] && echo "You have permissions to edit /etc/shadow." || echo "You do NOT have permissions to edit /etc/shadow."
```

But since you're learning it would be better if you had tried to solve it by yourself.

For more information refer to `help test` and `man bash`.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I still have a couple of questions here. As part of my learning, I have not yet come across the options of -f and -w so not sure how this works. Will find out these, and understand the coding first then would plan to implement it. However, could you please suggest some good book to start with from the perspective of only scripting, where the questions start from basics and gradually advances. It would be really of great help. Thanks again

Comment: @HeyatAfroz the character `[` is a synonym for the `test` command. `[[` is largely the same, and both are often built into the shell. You can learn about this by typing `help test` at a command prompt, or by reading the manual page (using `man bash`). In this case `-f` and `-w` are options to the `test` command: `-f` tests if a file exists, and `-w` tests if it is writable by you. One of the best resources for learning Bash shell scripting is this website: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the link for the book.